# Screen does not come back on after overnight on HP Z230 workstation

Tags: 14.04, monitor

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a HP Z230 workstation with dual monitors.  Very often in the morning, the screens are just blank and don't seem to wake up from suspend / power save mode.  To fix it, I need to go to `tty1` and reboot my PC.

I checked the "Power" settings and it's configured to "Don't Suspend" so it shouldn't be entering into any power save mode.  This only seems to happen only overnight - my monitors always come back fine after a 1 hr lunch.

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/questions/546818/displayport-monitor-not-detected-if-switched-off-and-on-again and detail whether you are having any of those issues.