# One monitor unresponsive upon startup

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, dual-graphics

I am running 16.04 with two monitors. One is connected via vga on my motherboard and the other via displayport on my (Nvidia) graphics card. Upon resuming from a suspension, during which both monitors were working correctly, only the vga monitor displays the login screen and the DP one is not even detected. My graphics card is still detected running the latest driver. The issue only occurs once the system has been suspended for a considerable amount of time (hours).

EDIT: My integrated graphics are those of an Intel i5-6500.

Output from `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'` (during the issue):

```
nick@nick-ubuntu-16-04lts:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1912] (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics [1043:8694]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b81] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:3302]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
```

EDIT2: Per David Foerster's suggestion I have linked the logs-

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/gHPmrvAG)

/var/log/pm-suspend.log  ---***Did not exist***

[sudo dmesg](https://pastebin.com/YN9E42e1)

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've added the info and the output from the command. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I know little about dual-graphics setups but there are a few log files that would help the people who do: `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and the output of `sudo dmesg`, all taken shortly after resume-from-suspend.

Comment: @DavidFoerster  Oddly, the problem only occurs after suspension for hours. I will post the logs once the problem recurs. Hopefully the question is not buried by then. Thanks

Comment: When you edit the question or post comments it is pushed to the top of the question list. Please don't abuse this to "bump" your question though! There are detection measures in place. ;-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Oh, thanks I didn't know that and not interested in gaming the system. Hopefully all the information that might be needed is now in my edits. Thanks again

Comment: Your problem is this displayport. This kind of connect cause headache even in Windows environment. Look [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546818/displayport-monitor-not-detected-if-switched-off-and-on-again), may help you.

Comment: @Redbob thanks for that. I can't ditch display port though because it's all my monitor supports (gsync 1.0). Any other suggestions? I can't believe this is such an issue. Display port is a well established standard and will probably only grow...