# Mouse and Keyboard No Longer Work After Changing Graphics Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, keyboard, mouse

In an attempt to solve several issues ([One monitor unresponsive upon startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959388/one-monitor-unresponsive-upon-startup) and the other being that files and folders were not displaying on my desktop) I attempted to switch the drivers for my NVidia card. First, I switched to Nouveau and while the second issue was resolved, I was no longer able to use cuda. So, I switched to an older NVidia driver and now after booting the keyboard nor mouse work (no mouse pointer etc. but the display of the switching to ethernet connection and the time all still happen on screen. What is the issue? Thanks

Comment: I did a comment at other issue, CircArgs. When you'll be able to solve that issue, this will be solved, too. Mouse and keyboard are managed by Xorg, too.